# Creating URL String of a Custom URL Mapping on gsp

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I've modified the default URL mapping of a certain Grails `Controller`:

**BankRemittanceController.groovy**

```
class BankRemittanceController{
    def view(String bankCode, String refNo) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**UrlMappings.groovy**

```
class UrlMappings {
    ...

    /*
     * Will accomodate the following URLs
     *
     * /project/remittance/bank/
     * /project/remittance/bank/hsbc/
     * /project/remittance/bank/hsbc/8959-87s-777-EI-02
     */

    "/remittance/bank/$bankCode?/$refNo?"{
        controller={"bankRemittance"}
        action=[GET:"show"]
    }

    ...
}
```

And I've tested these URL and it works. The problem is when I try to dynamically generate URL String on a `.gsp`, it produces the default URL instead:

```
<script>
    var redirectURL = "${g.createLink(controller: "remittance", action: "view")}"

    // The URL generated here is still:
    // /project/bankRemittance/view
    // 
    // instead of the mapped URL in UrlMappings.groovy:
    // /project/remittance/bank
    //
</script>
```

How can I generate my expected URL String?

Comment: var redirectURL = "${g.createLink(controller: "remittance", action: "view")}" firstly missing the $ in that.. secondly you are telling the functionality g.createLink to create link for remittance/view it will not know about your url mappings. :) Once a user clicks it - if mapping redirects then so be it

Comment: @vahid Oh, about that, it's a typo.

Comment: @vahid And it doesn't redirect, it throws an `Error: 404` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change the declaration of the defined mapping. From

```
"/remittance/bank/$bankCode?/$refNo?"{
    controller={"bankRemittance"}
    action=[GET:"show"]
}
```

Make it as:

```
name mappingName: "/remittance/bank/$bankCode?/$refNo?"{
    controller={"bankRemittance"}
    action=[GET:"show"]
}
```

Then use the [createLink() `mapping` attribute](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html) instead of `controller` and `action` when declaring it on your `.gsp`:

```
<script>
    var redirectURL = "${g.createLink(mapping: "mappingName")}"
</script>
```

If you want to pass the two optional params (`bankCode` and `refNo`), use createLink() `params` attribute:

```
<script>
    var redirectURL = "${g.createLink(mapping: "mappingName",
        params: [bankCode: "...", refNo: "...")}"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why in mapping you are calling non existing action 'show' .
I have changed it to :  action=[GET:"view"]

if your expected url is : /project/remittance/bank , 
you can use : ${g.createLink(controller: "remittance", action: "bank")}
or: ${g.createLink(uri: "/remittance/bank")}